# Prevent UISearchController from hiding view Navigation Bar in IOS8

Tags: ios8, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a UIViewController embedded in a popover. This controller has two subviews, a UINavigationBar and a UITableView. I try to implement the new search API (as SearchDisplayControlled is deprecated in iOS8).

When I click in the search bar (displaying two scopes), everything is all right, and the navigation bar is still visible. But when I start typing in the search bar, the navigation bar disappears, replaced by a blank area. I tried to add `self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;` in the `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` method, but got no result. (note that the controller `viewDidLoad defines self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`)

Any idea to force navigation being displayed anytime?

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same effect - in my case setting the property in `viewDidLoad` in my view controller made the navigation bar stick around:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    ...
}
```

When I'd previously set the same property from a class that was managing the search (initialized after `-viewDidLoad` had already been called on the VC), I saw the same behaviour of a blank nav bar that you describe.

Comment: Didn't fix it for me

Answer (score 1):

This work for me

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = true;
```